# Assimp cmake build windows big .lib files

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, assimp

I'm trying to build assimp for windows using cmake. I've solved some earlier issues with /MD thanks to some great people here. Currently the problem is that the output files (.lib and DLL) are big.

I've followed general advice on shrinking file size. Disabled testing, export and using -Os. Here is part of the CMakeLists file:

```
# All supported options ###############################################

OPTION( BUILD_SHARED_LIBS
  "Build package with shared libraries."
  OFF
)
OPTION( ASSIMP_BUILD_FRAMEWORK
  "Build package as Mac OS X Framework bundle."
  OFF
)
OPTION( ASSIMP_DOUBLE_PRECISION
  "Set to ON to enable double precision processing"
  OFF
)
OPTION( ASSIMP_OPT_BUILD_PACKAGES
  "Set to ON to generate CPack configuration files and packaging targets"
  OFF
)
OPTION( ASSIMP_ANDROID_JNIIOSYSTEM
  "Android JNI IOSystem support is active"
  OFF
)
OPTION( ASSIMP_NO_EXPORT
  "Disable Assimp's export functionality."
  ON
)
OPTION( ASSIMP_BUILD_ZLIB
  "Build your own zlib"
  OFF
)
OPTION( ASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS
  "If the supplementary tools for Assimp are built in addition to the library."
  OFF
)
OPTION ( ASSIMP_BUILD_SAMPLES
  "If the official samples are built as well (needs Glut)."
  OFF
)
OPTION ( ASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS
  "If the test suite for Assimp is built in addition to the library."
  OFF
)
OPTION ( ASSIMP_COVERALLS
  "Enable this to measure test coverage."
  OFF
)
OPTION( ASSIMP_INSTALL
  "Disable this if you want to use assimp as a submodule."
  ON
)
OPTION ( ASSIMP_ERROR_MAX
  "Enable all warnings."
  OFF
)
OPTION ( ASSIMP_ASAN
  "Enable AddressSanitizer."
  OFF
)
OPTION ( ASSIMP_UBSAN
  "Enable Undefined Behavior sanitizer."
  OFF
)
OPTION ( ASSIMP_BUILD_DOCS
  "Build documentation using Doxygen."
  OFF
)
OPTION( ASSIMP_INJECT_DEBUG_POSTFIX
  "Inject debug postfix in .a/.so/.dll lib names"
  ON
)

OPTION ( ASSIMP_IGNORE_GIT_HASH
   "Don't call git to get the hash."
   OFF
)
```

Combined with the following cmake command

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-Os"  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/MD /EHsc" ..
```

Which gives some warnings but doesn't fail. Here's the log:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30038.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30038.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Shared libraries disabled
-- Looking for ZLIB...
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
-- Could not locate ZLIB
-- compiling zlib from sources
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Build an import-only version of Assimp.
-- Enabled importer formats: AMF 3DS AC ASE ASSBIN B3D BVH COLLADA DXF CSM HMP IRRMESH IRR LWO LWS M3D MD2 MD3 MD5 MDC MDL NFF NDO OFF OBJ OGRE OPENGEX PLY MS3D COB BLEND IFC XGL FBX Q3D Q3BSP RAW SIB SMD STL TERRAGEN 3D X X3D GLTF 3MF MMD
-- Disabled importer formats:
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Results in a whopping 122 MB .lib file. For comparison, on Android, I get a 12 MB .so file. Already tried without /MD, results in comparable size.

Any idea how to shrink down the .lib files? Are there any settings in VS compiler a can try out?

Answer (score 0):

The .lib file is **either** a static library **or** an import library for a DLL on Windows. The Android .so file is a shared object library that is an equivalent for a DLL on Windows.

According to your CMakeLists file and the size of the resulting lib you are building the static lib. To build the DLL version of assimp you need to set `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` to `ON`. This can be done on the CMake command line for a 64bit Visual Studio 2019 build e.g. as follows:

```
cmake -S <sourcedir> -B <builddir> -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64
```

Comment: I referred to static .lib file. I know how to switch between static and shared in assimp, the CMakeLists.txt is quite clear. I do have a preference for static linking. But for comparison, the Android .a library is 40 MB. Which is acceptable. 120MB is too big IMHO. Any ideas how to shrink it down?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Assimp uses C++ STD and STL features and the MSVC implementations of the Standard Library and STL are notoriously known for producing huge static libraries. Sorry.

Comment: One more question. Is it then also normal that the DLL for the exact same build settings (besides BUILD_SHARED_LIBS off course) is only 5 MB. Is that normal as well?

Comment: Yes, I would expect that. But the DLL size depends on whether you link against the static or dynamic runtime libraries, i.e. use `/MT` or `/MD`.